# No Wi-Fi adapter found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless

After replacing Windows 7 with Ubuntu 20.04 on my ASUS, I am unable to connect to Wi-Fi, since the settings page says "no Wi-Fi adapter found". I tried some things mentioned in similar threads, like reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source (although I didn't really understand what I was doing - I am a complete beginner), but that didn't work. 
I suppose the relevant lines from output for `lshw -C network` are:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff
```

Also, `rfkill list all` doesn't produce any output. Could someone help me to at least understand what the problem might be?

Comment: I can help to understand what is the problem. You have a `MT7630e` wireless device that is not properly supported by the linux kernel. I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: What happens if you do this in terminal `sudo modprobe mt76x0e`

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you! Now I know what specifically to search for.

Comment: @Jeremy31 It doesn't output anything.

Comment: Do the results for `lshw -C network` still show unclaimed?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to provide results from the wireless-info.txt file